# Is my JUnit test for delete operation correct?

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, ormlite

I want to write JUnit test for delete operation that call delete method ORMLite library (it is not important). I'm mocking behaviour of ORMLite API in my tests. But I'm not sure that I created the correct test and that I'm really testing delete operation.

So, I have defined some datasource class with operations `create(List<Object> o), read(Object o), delete (Object o)`. Here is simplified code.

```
class ObjectDataSource {

    public void create (List<Object> o) {
        ormapi.create(o);    
    }

    public List<Object> read (Object o ) {
        return ormapi.queryForMatching(o);
    }

    public void delete (Object o) {
        ormapi.delete(o);
    }

}
```

Now,I here is created JUnit test. It's testing that Object was really removed.

```
@Test
public void readTest() {
    // ormlite api init
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Object, Integer> dao = mock(RuntimeExceptionDao.class);
    ObjectDbHelper dbHelper = new ObjectDbHelper(context, dao);
    ObjectDataSource dataSource = new ObjectDataSource(context, dbHelper);

    // data init
    Object object = new Object() {{ setId(47); }};
    Object completeObject = new Object {{ setId(47); setObjectName("test object"); }}
    List<Object> list = ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(completeObject);

    // api mocking
    when(dao.queryForMatching(object)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());

    // testing
    dataSource.create(list);
    dataSource.delete(object);
    List<Object> readList = dataSource.read(object);
    Assert.assertEquals(new ArrayList<Object>(), readList);
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to your question - but it's not really a good use of your time to unit test one-line methods.  Unit testing finds problems with the logic in your code.  A one-line method has no logic, so there is nothing to be gained by unit testing it.  Please focus your testing effort on code that could actually fail, rather than on code that really can't.

Comment: I accept your comment, but this issue simplifies the problem. I focus only for correct testing of delete operation. There is also other logic, but I want to make this issue more clear.

Comment: To know how best to test a method, it is important to know what that method is intended to achieve.  A test ensures that the intention is fulfilled.  If the intention is as simple as "method X should call method Y", then there's no value at all in a test - you can just look at the code to see that method X calls method Y. A test is only valuable when there is some logic around the call; for example, in circumstance A, method X calls method Y, but in circumstance B, method X calls method Z. My opinion is that by over-simplifying your question, you've turned it into something slightly pointless.

Comment: yeah, you are right. It lost the sense of testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be checking that `delete()` has been called. You probably need something like:

```
@Test
public void readTest() {
    // ormlite api init
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Object, Integer> dao = mock(RuntimeExceptionDao.class);
    ObjectDbHelper dbHelper = new ObjectDbHelper(context, dao);
    ObjectDataSource dataSource = new ObjectDataSource(context, dbHelper);

    // data init
    Object object = new Object() {{ setId(47); }};
    Object completeObject = new Object {{ setId(47); setObjectName("test object"); }}
    List<Object> list = ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(completeObject);

    // testing
    dataSource.create(list);
    dataSource.delete(object);

    // verify that ObjectDataSource class correctly invokes delete
    // method on DAO:
    verify(dao).delete(object);
}
```

I see no benefit in calling `dataSource.read()` and testing the result, since you've faked that result with your mocked DAO object. It doesn't really tell you anything. It's like setting `int x = 5;` and then checking `x` is `5`.

Also, your test is very misleadingly named if your intention is to check deletion works... Something like `deleteTest` might be a better name :-)

Comment: Your code is not clear, because in existing code I mocked `dao.queryForMatching()` and you verify `delete()`. `dao.delete()` is called from `datasource.delete()`, but there is not required no when-then behaviour?

Comment: @misco The complete code I was suggested is in my edited answer. I see no reason for you to mock `dao.queryForMatching()`, since you are testing delete. Of course, all this testing assumes your `Object` class has a proper equals method defined.